# Logical functions

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How many Logical functions (of 10 variables) that have"1" on set

I suppose that $ 2^{1023}$

because of all the options $ 2^{2^{10}} = 2^{1024}$

and 1 will be exactly half

Is it so?

Comment: It is true that there are $2^{1024}$ "logical" functions of $10$ variables, but what do you mean by "having '1' on set?"

Comment: Function Result

Comment: That does not help.

Comment: Taking at least one time the value 1?

Comment: As I understood the teaching, you need to calculate how many different functions will be equal to 1
For any given values of 10 variables

Comment: those. for example with such a set 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 .
How many functions can be, which take the value 1?

Comment: If you want *always* 1, there is only **one** function!

Comment: And if you want at least a $1$, there are $2^{1024}-1$ functions.  All of them except the one that is always $0$.

Comment: Functions can take values either 0 or 1.
Then for a certain set of variables, how many functions will be equal to 1.
I thought half or I'm wrong.

Comment: Work out the case of the $16$ functions of $2$ variables.  They can be weritten $0000$, $0001$, $0010$, ... $1111$.  How many satisfy your definition?

Comment: In this case, 1, when there will be 1111
But if we consider a particular case, but an example when the variables 0 and 1, then the functions that will be equal to 1 will be 8

Comment: *What* 8 functions will be "equal to 1"  according you?

Comment: Well, I mean for this case, if we consider only this line, then there will be 8 "1" and 8 "0", but this does not mean that the entire function takes values for all cases

Comment: **What** 8 will be 1?